# iOS: Getting high-res video from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to let user pick a video to use in my app. It works fine but the resolution is always 720p. Is there any way how to get 1080p or even better 4K?

This is my code. `videoQuality` doesn't do anything and setting `allowsEditing` to `false` also did not help.

```swift
func showVideoPicker() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary) ?? []
        assert(!picker.mediaTypes.isEmpty)
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I hope this is supported because otherwise it looks like I need to build my own picker.

PS: I have iOS 13 project.

**SOLUTION**: There is `picker.videoExportPreset` property used to control the resolution of the compressed videos. And here are predefined constants from `AVFoundation` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_preset_names_for_quicktime_files_of_a_given_size

Comment: make sure you have not limited the video quality in your device septings

Comment: @LeoDabus good point. Thanks. Can you elaborate? I found only options for transfering media to Mac.

Comment: Settings > Camera > Record video

Comment: Got it. I have 4K enabled. And all the videos I have tested are either 1080p or 4K.